# Javascript to Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

So I have this javascript That works by itself

```
function update_checkboxes()
      {
        var part_array = [];
        $("input#edit:checked").parents('td').next().each(function(){
          part_id = $(this).text();
          part_array.push(part_id);
        });
        $("input#participant_ids").val(JSON.stringify(part_array));
      }
```

That I converted to coffeescript

```
update_checkboxes = ->
    part_array = []
    $("input#edit:checked").parents("td").next().each ->
      part_id = $(this).text()
      part_array.push part_id

    $("input#participant_ids").val JSON.stringify(part_array)
```

The problem is when I do rails `rake assets:precompile`, it compile fine but in Firebug I gives error

```
ReferenceError: part_array is not defined

$("input#participant_ids").val(JSON.stringify(part_array));
```

due that the part_array gets defined in a different block.

```
update_checkboxes = function() {
    var part_array;
    return part_array = [];
  };

  $("input#edit:checked").parents("td").next().each(function() {
    var part_id;
    part_id = $(this).text();
    return part_array.push(part_id);
  });

  $("input#participant_ids").val(JSON.stringify(part_array));

}).call(this);
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: maybe your inconsistent tabs? (4 spaces under `update_checkboxes`), then you use 2

Comment: I would say your indention is off, this script looks good to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that in CoffeeScript, indentation **matters**, and you can't mix spaces and tabs reliably.

This CoffeeScript, in which indentation has been standardized to two spaces:

```
update_checkboxes = ->
  part_array = []
  $("input#edit:checked").parents("td").next().each ->
    part_id = $(this).text()
    part_array.push part_id

  $("input#participant_ids").val JSON.stringify(part_array)
```

Results in this JavaScript:

```
var update_checkboxes;
update_checkboxes = function() {
  var part_array;
  part_array = [];
  $("input#edit:checked").parents("td").next().each(function() {
    var part_id;
    part_id = $(this).text();
    return part_array.push(part_id);
  });
  return $("input#participant_ids").val(JSON.stringify(part_array));
};
```

...which doesn't end up with `part_array` defined in a separate block.

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation must be off. I pasted your **exact** coffeescript from the question into [js2coffee](http://js2coffee.org)

```
update_checkboxes = ->
    part_array = []
    $("input#edit:checked").parents("td").next().each ->
      part_id = $(this).text()
      part_array.push part_id

    $("input#participant_ids").val JSON.stringify(part_array)
```

and received...

```
var update_checkboxes;

update_checkboxes = function() {
  var part_array;
  part_array = [];
  $("input#edit:checked").parents("td").next().each(function() {
    var part_id;
    part_id = $(this).text();
    return part_array.push(part_id);
  });
  return $("input#participant_ids").val(JSON.stringify(part_array));
};
```

Which is correct. StackOverflow must have normalized your indentation when you pasted it. Take a look at the original and fix the mismatched indentation.